# Different file extension .WVPbbl instead of WVP.bib

Tags: bibliographies

I have downloaded and extracted 2 files from [this](https://arxiv.org/e-print/1907.00284) ArXiVe file.
 They have file extensions *.tex* and *.bbl*.

However when I compile the WVP.tex with LaTeX, it complains that there doens't exist a *WVP.bib* file:

So how do I tell WInEdt 9.0 that it should use **WVP.bbl** instead ?

**THIS IS WVP.blg file :**

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: WVP.aux
The style file: plain.bst
I couldn't open database file WVP.bib
---line 36 of file WVP.aux
: \bibdata{WVP
:             }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file WVP.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "AdaRosTrnLimitClosed"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "AdaRosInjectivity"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "AdaRosLocallyPresentable"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "HedPulFullEmbeddings"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "KanHigherInfinite" 
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "ZemInnerModels"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "VopPulHedRigidRelation"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

**This is WVP.bbl file which was not recognized and used:**

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{AdaRosTrnLimitClosed}
J.~Ad\'{a}mek, J.~Rosick\'{y}, and V.~Trnkov\'{a}.
\newblock Are all limit-closed subcategories of locally presentable categories
  reflective?
\newblock In {\em Categorical algebra and its applications
  ({L}ouvain-{L}a-{N}euve, 1987)}, volume 1348 of {\em Lecture Notes in Math.},
  pages 1--18. Springer, Berlin, 1988.

\bibitem{AdaRosInjectivity}
Ji\v{r}\'{\i} Ad\'{a}mek and Ji\v{r}\'{\i} Rosick\'{y}.
\newblock On injectivity in locally presentable categories.
\newblock {\em Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.}, 336(2):785--804, 1993.

\bibitem{AdaRosLocallyPresentable}
Ji\v{r}\'{\i} Ad\'{a}mek and Ji\v{r}\'{\i} Rosick\'{y}.
\newblock {\em Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories}, volume 189 of
  {\em London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series}.
\newblock Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1994.

\bibitem{HedPulFullEmbeddings}
Z.~Hedrl\'{\i}n and A.~Pultr.
\newblock On full embeddings of categories of algebras.
\newblock {\em Illinois J. Math.}, 10:392--406, 1966.

\bibitem{KanHigherInfinite}
Akihiro Kanamori.
\newblock {\em The Higher Infinite}.
\newblock Springer Monographs in Mathematics. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, second
  edition, 2009.

\bibitem{VopPulHedRigidRelation}
P.~Vop\v{e}nka, A.~Pultr, and Z.~Hedrl\'{\i}n.
\newblock A rigid relation exists on any set.
\newblock {\em Comment. Math. Univ. Carolinae}, 6:149--155, 1965.

\bibitem{ZemInnerModels}
Martin Zeman.
\newblock {\em Inner Models and Large Cardinals}, volume~5 of {\em De Gruyter
  Series in Logic and its Applications}.
\newblock Walter de Gruyter \& Co., Berlin, 2002.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: the bbl file is the _output_ from bibtex, so you do not need to run bibtex again (and you can not run it if you don't have the .bib source)  just run latex on the tex file and that bbl will be included.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I'm running WinEdt 9.0. How do I **don't** run bib tex if I'm running LaTeX from the command line or from WinEdt??

Comment: on the command line it is simple just type `pdflatex WVP` and don't type `bibtex WVP` ,   winedt presumably has an option to just run latex and not bibtex but I do not know that editor.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle @DavidCarlisle the command "pdflatex WVP.tex" from the command line in Win 8.1 still complaines: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(WVP.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amscls\amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2009/07/02 v2.20.1
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmat

Comment: @DavidCarlisle (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\jknappen\mathrsfs.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\url\url.sty) (WVP.aux)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\jknappen\ursfs.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `AdaRosTrnLimitClosed' on page 1 undefined on input lin
e 92.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `AdaRosInjectivity' on page 1 undefined on input line 9
6.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `AdaRosLocallyPresentable' on page 1 undefined on input
 line 98.

Comment: as always it takes two latex runs to resolve cross references, run latex again

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've run it many times, but no iprovement :-(

Comment: either the bbl file will be input and the cross refs should work, or there should be a warning in the log that it is not found, what does the log say?

Comment: unrelated but `LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>` you have not updated miktex for 5 years?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The problem is even worse: some tokens are left [untranslated](http://leteckaposta.cz/394100856) They are just underlined with a solid line but not treated anyhow by WinEdt.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually this is well possible, I do not even know how to update it? Do you think that this is the issue and the problem with the error?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle there is a strange file with exactly these toekns in WVP.aux: \relax
\citation{AdaRosTrnLimitClosed}
\citation{AdaRosInjectivity}
\citation{AdaRosLocallyPresentable}
\citation{HedPulFullEmbeddings}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{1}{Introduction}}{1}}
\citation{KanHigherInfinite}
\newlabel{item:crit}{{1}{2}}
\newlabel{item:V-beta}{{2}{2}}
\newlabel{item:coherence}{{3}{2}}
\newlabel{thm:ord-woodin-implies-swvp}{{1.5}{2}}
\citation{KanHigherInfinite}
\citation{ZemInnerModels}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Pleaase see my new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500358/what-relax-command-means)

Comment: you still have not shown your log file, also make sure you have not over-written the .bbl file with bad bibtex runs

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is [here](http://leteckaposta.cz/408667174) I have fixed up the problem with missing references by copying the .bbl file to the end of the .tex file and it works fine. However without this appending, it is a mystery for me how to achieve the result.

Comment: as you have provided no log, it will be a mystery for anybody else as well, so this question will remain unanswered. As you have something working I suggest we close the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have provided the log in the comment above where I write "It is [here](http://leteckaposta.cz/408667174) I have fixed up the problem..."

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And without the appended refernces from .bbl it is [here](http://leteckaposta.cz/531571753)

Comment: I didn't notice the link, it would be better to add the log to your question, but that log shows no bbl file being included and no message `No file xxxx.bbl` so there can not be a `\bibliography` command in your file.

Comment: **Finally** you provide the log:-) Now I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments you finally provided the log file which explains the issue.  The log says

```
[13] (WVP.bbl

LaTeX Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 3.

) [14] (WVP.aux)
```

So the `bbl` file was input by `\bibliography{WVP}` but it was empty and did not define any references. In particular that means it is not the file that you included in the question which had a non empty `thebibliography` environment.

I would guess that in earlier attempts to run bibtex with no `.bib` input file, you over-wrote the `bbl` file with an empty version.

However when you pasted the original bibliography into the main file, it of course all worked and defined the references.

Comment: You are right. When extracted, the .bbl file is **non-empty**. After pdftexify it becomes empty with only \thebibliography commands. This is a strange feature of WinEdt 9.0 ...But finally we know the reason why it does the [?] references undefined.

Comment: @user2925716 no it is not strange it as I guessed in an early comment, you ran bibtex so over-wrote the original file but with no .bib file the generated bibliography is empty see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500306/different-file-extension-wvpbbl-instead-of-wvp-bib?noredirect=1#comment1263759_500306

Comment: I do not follow how you have concluded that ` so there can not be a \bibliography command in your file ?` I didn't notice the link, it would be better to add the log to your question, but that log shows no bbl file being included and no message No file xxxx.bbl so there can not be a \bibliography command in your file. **I have cretaed an empty .bib file and the deletion of bbl still persists ....**

Comment: @user2925716 the first log you posted (not the one I quoted) had no `(WPV.bbl` showing a bbl included and no message saying a `bbl` file is missing so that is from a document with no `\bibliography` command. Which is OK, that was the log from the version in which you had replaced that by the bibliography.

Comment: But WHY is the .bbl file keeping deleting when I run pdflatex on WVP.tex file even when I have created a WVP.bib file ??

Comment: you won't get a usable bibliography generated unless you have a bib file with the correct entries, but bibtex will only over-write it with a file with no entries it won't delete the file, perhaps the "pdftexify" thing which is a miktex wrapper that I have never used deletes the file if there is an error, I don't know.

Comment: I GOT THIS EXPLANATION FROM THE CREATOR OF WINEDT 9.0: No. WinEdt does not do that. PDFTeXify command assumes that bbl

file was created with bibtex from bib sources and WinEdt runs

bibtex.exe to update the bbl file. Since your file was created by

other means you should not run bibtex or PDFTeXify as you don't

even have a bib file.

 

You must run PDFLaTeX and then your bbl file will not be replaced

by an empty one since WinEdt will not run bibtex.

 

That's all.

Comment: And it works fine!