# what \relax command means?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, winedt, token-lists

I'm trying to compile [this](https://arxiv.org/e-print/1907.00284) .tex file from ArXiVe.org in WinEdt 9.0 but some **tokens** are underlined with a solid line and
preceeded by a strange command

\relax
command in WVP.aux:

```
\relax
\citation{AdaRosTrnLimitClosed}
\citation{AdaRosInjectivity}
\citation{AdaRosLocallyPresentable}
\citation{HedPulFullEmbeddings}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\tocsection}  {1}{Introduction}}{1}}
\citation{KanHigherInfinite}
\newlabel{item:crit}{{1}{2}}
\newlabel{item:V-beta}{{2}{2}}
\newlabel{item:coherence}{{3}{2}}
\newlabel{thm:ord-woodin-implies-swvp}{{1.5}{2}}
```

NOT ALL are references, how do I **get rid of from the underlining**?

Actually I solved the missing references [?] by including the WVP.bbl to the end of WVP.tex as asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500306/different-file-extension-wvpbbl-instead-of-wvp-bib).

[image]

Comment: That is all a perfectly normal aux file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just wonder why some commands like "enumerate" are **underlined** in that WVP.tex file in WInEdt ?? How do I get rid of this underlining?

Comment: I have no idea about winedt, sorry. But that is unrelated to the question about `\relax` (the site works best if you do not ask unrelated questions in the same posting)

Comment: In your screenshot winedt underlines the argument of label commands and some environments. That's quite normal. You can change the highlighting, but I see no reason why you would want this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\relax` is a tex primitive command that is non expandable but is defined to do nothing at all, it is useful in several contexts as a delimiter of various sorts.

LaTeX always writes one to the start of the aux file for reasons that are not well documented (it does nothing useful) but probably because some file systems had problems with empty, zero length files so by writing `\relax` to the aux file LaTeX ensures that it is never empty.